# How can I prevent force fields from affecting hair or other particles?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, force-fields

I want the turbulence force field to only affect my smoke sim, but it's also messing up my hair particles. I've tried setting Effector Collection to the collection the smoke simulation is in (the hair is in a different one).

EDIT: project file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O7bqU8FNCZyATB6S46CRcYuGLIb2OSEb

Comment: Can you include the blend file too

Comment: @covector sure, i'll add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the effector collection to the collection the hair emitter is in and the hair stopped moving. You should set it to the collection that the hair is in instead of the collection the smoke is in.

[image: Effector collection]

Comment: ooooh so i need to set the *hair* field weights to it's collection. i thought only the emmiter would be affected if i set it's own field weights to it's own collection. cheers!