# Appending hair object to file messes up another hair object

Tags: particles, hair, append

whenever I append a princess hair from another file to my current blend file, all object within the current file with particle system is messing up. I am really new to the particle system and I can't figure out how to fix that.

[image: pirate hat before appending another hair object]

[image: princess hair before appeining]

[image]

I am attaching two separate blend files with pirate hair and princess' hair. I really don't know what can cause the problem, but sometimes when I entered a material preview mode with one of the hair object (in the current file with pirate hat and others) the blender crashed with "segmentation fault"

Pirate hair file
[image]

princess hair file
[image]

Comment: @vklidu looking forward to see! I also discovered if I delete plane with hair in princes file and then append just bezier curve, then the pirate's hair is starting to follow the bezier curve as well

Comment: Here is the script  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214880/2214 ...

Comment: @vklidu actually I have found out that the curve's field force affects all other particle systems so that's the reason, but I cannot manage to isolate that force only for the princess hair

Comment: Sure it affects :) see [How to isolate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165993/how-can-i-prevent-force-fields-from-affecting-hair-or-other-particles)  ... BTW I tried to delete Force Field Curve and append pirate's hair again and it results in the same condition. I also tried append my hair edit and it worked fine (without the script) ... so I was wrong with edit issue (to clean it up here I deleted my irrelevant comment).

Comment: Now I see your issue (and why isolate Curve Guide didn't work) ... you have set Force Field also for princess hair emitter :) ... also refresh cache go to edit mode and back with pirate's hair emitter.

Comment: @vklidu thank you, I have solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by going to the particle settings of both princess and pirate hair -> field weights -> set effector to the collections where each hair is located